# In Angular JS, click event bound on a directive, does not make the directive interpolate certain parameter

Tags: angularjs

I am learning directives and I am not sure why this directive code is not working:

```
define([
    'appConfig'
], function() {

    angular.module('appDirectives').directive('workspaceCanvas', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {},
            template: '<h1>Hello there, I am {{name}}</h1>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.name = 'Dany';

                var self = scope;

                element.bind('click', function() {
                    console.log('clicked');
                    self.name = 'Ted';
                    console.log(self.name)
                });

            }
          };
    });
});
```

When I add the directive to the DOM, I can see the name **"Dany"** being interpolated.

But when I click on the element, even if I **capture the scope** and assign the value **Ted** to **scope**'s **name** property, **the change does not interpolate on the view**.

Any idea why?

Comment: You need to call the digest loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element.bind('click', function() {
     console.log('clicked')
     scope.$apply(function () {
         self.name = "Ted";
     });
     console.log(self.name)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the digest loop. Inside the click event add the last statment `scope.$apply();`

or even better

```
scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.name = "Ted";
});
```